# Using Bicep as IaC tool to handle external infrastructure changes

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

We have infrastructure as code (IaC) using Bicep, which is as we understood, without state management.

One of the resources we have is the virtual network resource.

The issue here is that the virtual network peerings are handled outside of IaC.
And we will have a lot of peerings between this and other virtual networks in another subscription within the same tenant. They are added on demand (triggered by the user, but automated/scripted) when needed.

The plan is to have the deployment workflow/action running on schedule. The deployment mode is incremental.

Is there a smart way to handle the peering? So that they are not removed (due to a mismatch between code and actual resources) when the deployment runs?
We would not like to have the peerings in IaC if not necessary.

The 'existing' keyword will cause the deployment to fail if the workflow is triggered to set up the whole infrastructure from a clean state.

Maybe it can be handled by using some kind of a state/JSON file with all the network peering information? And somehow from the deployment workflow, grab the information from this extra file?
But then we would like to have another workflow to keep this file updated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you don't specify the peering in your bicep and the on-demand peering ONLY do peering there won't be any conflict.

Comment: We don't specify peering in our Bicep template. And the on-demand peering is done using Ansible module azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualnetworkpeering. But how come that there won't be any conflict? We tried to incremental deployment using the -whatif switch, and we could see that the delete operation will be applied to the virtualNetworkPeerings array within the virtual network resource properties, if we ran the deployment without the whatif switch.

Comment: if you dont specify virtualNetworkPeerings  in your vnet resource that will work. give it a try on a test vnet. Btw whatif is not reliable. If you search online you'll fine some article / so post related

Comment: Just tried to deploy the virtual network resource with only 'addressSpace' inside 'properties'. Ran the test deployment with -whatif, and saw that it will remove virtualNetworkPeerings information on that existing resource.

Comment: already told you what-if is giving you wrong information

Comment: @Thomas, thanks for your input. Just tried to run the deployment without the 'what-if'. Again, we only included the 'addressSpace' within 'properties' of the virtual network resource. However, the deployment failed because it indeed tried to remove something that we haven't included in our Bicep template. In this case it tried to delete a subnet, but failed since this was in use.

Comment: It is not related to the peering then. Yeah your subnets need to be defined inside the bicep file otherwise it will try to delete them (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72622826/4167200).

Comment: Yes, in the Bicep that we actually use, we have the subnets defined there. This was just a test. When using the --what-if, we saw that the subnets and peering would be removed. Since information is saying that --what-if is not reliable, we removed it to see what will actually happens. We did not witness the deletion of peering, as it already failed when it tried to remove the subnet which was in use.

Comment: then you prob wanna retest with the subnets defined in your bicep ....

Comment: @Thomas, thank you for the suggestion. We did a new test with the subnets defined in the Bicep file. And we could see that the peering information in the existing virtual network resource was indeed NOT removed. So the predictions from the --what-if was really just false positives.

Guess that this is because of the virtualNetworkPeerings is an own (sub) resource? Since the subnets in the virtual netowrk would be deleted, but not the peerings.
I am quite new to Bicep. :)